# Calling Java Swing from c++

Tags: java, c++, swing, wrapper

I had made a game engine in Java (based on Swing) and I wan't to translate it to c++ and to ease the process, I want to know how to call Java api from the c++.

Basically what I wan't to make is using a wrapper that wraps the java library and makes it available to use from c++.

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing to me. As I understand it game engine is the model of the game and should have no GUI code within it (that's the view's responsibility, not the engine) and in fact should be GUI library-agnostic. So it really should have little to do with Swing. Back to your question, the classic way of interfacing Java with C++ is via JNI or JNA. There are other ways as well including Sockets or CORBA or others.

Comment: I had already included the GUI in the Java version. What I just need is calling them from the C++ i.e, C++ classes extending Java classes

Comment: No, C++ classes extending Java classes simply can't be done as they're totally different beasts with different architecture. With JNI you can create C++ wrappers for Java classes, but as far as I know, that's about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use JNI. Try to keep the calls to primitive data types. It requires coversions when calling java from c++ and back. Following could be a good help.

http://www.steveolyo.com/JNI/JNI.html

Comment: Thanks. A valuable resource. +1